# Программирование под Android: аналог метода append() из jQuery

Tags: android

Как в программировании под Android (т. е. в Java с соответствующими библиотеками) **программно** добавить элемент (например, кнопку) в конец указанного по id контейнера? То есть если в контейнере уже что-то естьто добавляемый элемент должен вставить в конец.

Для тех, что владеет `JavaScript`: я сейчас спросил об аналоге метода `append()` библиотеки `jQuery`.

Вероятно, чтобы ответить на мой вопрос, нужно всего лишь исправить одну строчку в коде:

```
// Определяем контейнер по ID   
RelativeLayout Contnr = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Contnr);

// Создаём новый объект (например, textInput)
EditText InputTextA = new EditText(this);

// Добавляем его (данный метод добавит объект в начало контейнера,
// как показал эксперимент, поверх уже существующих.)
Contnr.addView(InputTextA);
```

На всякий случай ещё раз укажу, что мы не знаем наперёд, если ли в контейнере что-то и  если есть, по после какого именно из уже существующих объектов мы будем добавлять новый.

Answer (score 3):

`RelativeLayout` - layout с относительным расположением элементов, надо жестко указывать отношения детей, он для такой целине подойдет. Я для такой задачи реализовывал следующее поведение. Создается `LinearLayout` с вертикальной ориентацией растягивается на экран (или на контейнер). Когда добавляем элемент делаем следующее

если вертикальный `LinearLayout` пустой - добавляем в него горизонтальный `LinearLayout` с высотой и шириной `WRAP_CONTENT`, в который добавляем ребенка

когда добавили горизонтальный `LinearLayout` - добавляем детей в него до тех пор, пока его ширина меньше ширины родительского вертикального `LinearLayout`, как только ширина больше - создаем новый горизонтальный `LinearLayout` и помещаем элемент в него и так далее.

Так как родительский `Layout` вертикальный, получается что горизонтальные идут один за другим сверху вниз и сами заполняются равномерно.

Ну и так как это делается программно - мы всегда можем контролировать элементы - что именно находится в контейнере, их ширину итд